# magento 2.3.4: I want to put brand attributes value after the short description

Tags: magento2, layout, attributes, xml, magento2.3.4

I tried different xml code but unable to achieve.
I am getting attribute value using below code, but above the sku, I want to place it in the short description block after it's content.

```
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.brand" template="product/view/brand_info.phtml" before ="-">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer"</argument>
        </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

[image: block image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product.info.overview - is the short description block

product.info.brand - your block, and you should move it after the overview

For example:

view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.brand" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview" />
```

or change it directly in your xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.brand" template="product/view/brand_info.phtml" after ="product.info.overview">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: :D thanks man, actually I am a newbie